# Kähler manifold with negative sectional curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-manifolds, curvature, kahler-ricci-flow

Goldberg's theorem states that every almost Kähler manifold of constant curvature is Kähler if and only if the curvature is zero. This seems to contradict the fact that the sectional curvature of the unit disk is constant and equal to $-1,$ as well as the quotient of the unit ball.

Comment: Finding a reference for "Goldberg's theorem" will answer the question. Probably, there will be an assumption that complex dimension is $>1$. In fact, here it is: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-021-01/S0002-9939-1969-0238238-1/S0002-9939-1969-0238238-1.pdf

Comment: Thank you #Igor, but the quotient of the ball is of higher dimension

Comment: Unit disk=unit ball in $\mathbb C$ has complex dimension $1$.

Comment: I talk about the ball in $\mathbb {C} ^n$ ($B_n={z\in \mathbb {C}^n ; |z|<1}$).

Comment: The standard complete Kahler metric on the complex unit ball of dimension $>1$ does not have constant sectional curvature.